# Environment Specific application.properties file in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application, i want to create environment specific properties file. The packaging type of my application in war and i am executing it in embedded tomcat. I use sts and execute the main from sts itself.

1. Can i have environment specific properties file like application-${env-value}.properties?

In above case, env-value will have values as local/devl/test/prod

2. Where to set the env-value file? For local, i can set it as the jvm argument through sts
3. Who reads the application.properties in Spring Boot application.
4. How to load the environment specific properties file? For ex - if i set the database uid,pwd, schema etc in environment specific property file, in that case will the datasource be able to understand the properties in it?
5. Can i use application.properties and application-local.properties file at same time?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)? It basically is supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: I did but that is not working. So i have application.properties file and application-local.properties file at same location. application-local.properties file contain db related properties. application.properties has a single property in it regarding spring mvc . Also i added -Dprofile=local as debug configuration but this value is not getting picked up

Comment: because you need to set `spring.active.profiles` so use `-Dspring.active.profiles=local`. instead.

Comment: No Success sir. so instead of -Dprofile, i am now using -Dspring.active.profiles=local. And then in my configuration file i try to fetch the value String driverClassName = env.getProperty("driverClassName");   env is the Environment from spring

Comment: -Dspring.active.profiles=local i am setting as debug configuration

Comment: Worked. The property is "spring.profiles.active"

Comment: Half Information on this page - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html  and other half on this page - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: @user3534483 , kindly help me how you did it? where did you set spring.profiles.active ?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Spring Boot already [has support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for [profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles) based properties.

Simply add an `application-[profile].properties` file and specify the profiles to use using the `spring.profiles.active` property.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

This will load the `application.properties` and the `application-local.properties` with the latter overriding properties from the first.

Comment: Can we override the use of application properties with another file for specific profile without loading both of them ? For tests or dev for example ?

Comment: M. Deinum, I too have similar issue, I have application.yml and application-qa.yml and I gave -Dspring.profiles.active=qa, both files are getting read but  properties from application-qa.yml are not overwriting the properties from application.yml, I am always seeing properties from application.yml only ? is there any way to specify the priority ?

Comment: Hi Both,
This can solve your problems.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Example:    https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/

Comment: I am writing code for aws lambda and can pass this key=value as environment value - which can be accessed using System.getenv() - will it work ?

Comment: I have 4 application-{profile}.properties file. And I want to run the same jar file in different environment, let us say dev, test, prod. So i cant use -Dspring.profiles.active=local. Kindly correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible... The whole point of using the `-Dspring.profiles.active=` is that you CAN run it in multiple environments.

Comment: Do you know, if one key is not found in application-dev.prop file, in that case will it search in application.properties??

Comment: If we use "-Dspring.profiles.active=local" at beginning just after java it works...
it should be before application.jar

Comment: --spring.profiles.active=local to run with java -jar command. ex: java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 29):

Yes you can. Since you are using spring, check out `@PropertySource` anotation.

Anotate your configuration with

```
@PropertySource("application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

You can call it what ever you like, and add inn multiple property files if you like too. Can be nice if you have more sets and/or defaults that belongs to all environments (can be written with @PropertySource{...,...,...} as well).

```
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource("application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"),
  @PropertySource("my-special-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"),
  @PropertySource("overridden.properties")})
```

Then you can start the application with environment

```
-Dspring.active.profiles=test
```

In this example, name will be replaced with application-test-properties and so on.

Comment: Problem is that `$spring.profiles.active}` is an array/comma seperated string. So it might not do what you expect/want it to do when there are multiple profiles active.

Comment: That is true, but works fine for two profiles - one default and one defined with PropertySource.
For more advanced property handling, I think you will have to look outside Spring. Also PropertySource is only read during startup. Other, more advanced libraries for property handling, can change properties run-time as well.

Comment: This worked, but I still don't understand why I had to do this manually. In one of my other repository I didn't had to do this.

Answer (score 9):

we can do like this:

in *application.yml*:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test //modify here to switch between environments
    include:  application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml
```

in *application-test.yml*:

```
server:
  port: 5000
```

and in *application-local.yml*:

```
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 8080
```

then spring boot will start our app as we wish to.

Comment: Aren't you hardcoding the active profile this way?? :(

Comment: The explicit `include:` line seems redundant and repetitious.

Comment: @MarkHu The description *"redundant and repetitious"* seems redundant and repetitious.

Answer (score 2):

My point is, we shouldn't ask developers to create all environment configurations in a single go, as this risks exposing production settings to end developers.

According to the 12-Factor principles, environment-specific configurations should reside solely in the environment.

How do we handle this for CI/CD?

We can build Spring once and then promote it to other environments. However, if the Spring JAR contains all environment configurations, it poses a security risk as all environment variables are stored in Git.