# Loading Java Properties Files by Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources, load

I want to load  Properties Files in Java code.
But I use profile to config -Dspring.profiles.active=local or dev... 
How to load properties files by profile Something like this:

```
classpath:${spring.profiles.active}/test.properties
```

How to do that in Java code ?
I did as below, but get null.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream iStream = Helper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(iStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            iStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment Specific application.properties file in Spring Boot application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196451/environment-specific-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot-application)

Comment: But I use getResourceAsStream()  to load, it cannot get that file

Comment: Well you can't mix spring feature of `profiles` with plain file loading. The feature is available out-of-box in Spring boot which can be easily leveraged (*refer question to which I marked this as duplicate in earlier comment*)

Comment: Thank for your suggest. However, I have not solved my problem yet. I do not use spring boot, I used -Dspring.profiles.active=local to configure argument on Tomcat, but it cannot load properties by getResourceAsStream(), InputStream still null. My properties file is in src/main/resources/local/test.properties

Answer (score 0):

This is some working code for us:

```
String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
InputStream workSpacesFIS = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(activeProfile + "/customers.txt");
if (workSpacesFIS != null) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

***Loading Java Properties Files by Profile***

```
public Properties getProp() throws IOException {
        final Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(TestService.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
        String activeProfile = prop.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        prop.load(TestService.class.getResourceAsStream("/application-"+activeProfile+".properties"));
        return prop;

    }
```