# How to untrack certain lines in Spring Boot application.properties?

Tags: git, spring-boot

Is it possible to untrack certains lines in `application.properties?`

I want to push `application.properties`, but I don't want to push lines which are for email configuration.
e.g.:

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mail
spring.mail.password=pass
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: You can see my updated answer on how to specify your application properties on a file located elsewhere in the environment.

Comment: @N.Labrahmi Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to untrack single lines of a file, but you can untrack your whole `application.properties` file and point to it using an OS placeholder so it can be detected on your machine by Spring Boot like the following for example:

```
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.myapp/application.properties")
```

This way, you keep sensitive configuration data outside of git tracking. Another benefit is that you can have a different configuration file for each environment where you deploy your application.

> Alternatively, it is possible to specify a file: location to appoint a
>   properties file that is located elsewhere on your host environment:
>   `@PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")`

See: https://blog.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate configuration files for different environments.

Ex.
application.properties -It contain key and value like this.
spring.profiles.active=dev

It defines which profile is active at a time.

Create other property file as per requirement like this and write your configuration in this files.

application-dev.properties

application-prod.properties

Comment: How can I allow spring boot to see that file? It doesn't see that file when running the application so `JavaMailSender` throws an error saying that no host provided

Comment: No need other configuration. Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196451/environment-specific-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot-application