# Load Values from configuration File using spring

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a clean way to load values from properties file using the environment value passed from the command line (maven project). I then plan to use the loaded values in Java cucumber test.

Usage : mvn test -Denvironment=staging (it then loads the values from the staging file i.e. application-staging.properties, etc).

I know spring boot offers profiles, wondering if I can do this use a clean approach using the generic spring framework (annotations).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196451/environment-specific-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: Isn't that related to Spring Boot?

Comment: Oops, sorry yes it is - my apologies.

Comment: For straigt Spring, check out the PropertySource annotation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: I've got following code and running using mvn test -Denvironment= dev (i've got a file called dev.properties) but I am getting null when trying to print url. \@Configuration
\@PropertySource("classpath:${environment}.properties")
public class AppTest 
{
    \@Value("${base.url}")
    private String url;

    \@Bean
    public Config getConfig(){
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setUrl(url);
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {

        System.out.println("The URL is : "+ getConfig().getUrl());
      
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @racraman. I am able to get this to work using your suggestion around `PropertySource`. In order to get different environment working i've used something like :

`@PropertySource({"classpath:${env}.properties"})`.

Cheers !!!

Comment: Great - glad you got it working !  By the way, `@PropertySource` does not resolve `@Value` annotations.  Instead, you have to use the `@Autowired` Environment as shown in the Example Usage in the doc.  Just below that is a section on using `@Value`, but I've never done that.

Comment: Thanks @racraman. I've used \@Value to setup a default value and it seems to be working fine. As you've mentioned in your comment I've actually used \@Autowired to work with the populated value. Thanks once again !!!