# How to tell spring boot which property files to load according to the server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, application.properties

I have this scenario where I need to load properties file according to the server name.

I have `resource` in this structure.

I have 2 different servers. let say SERV-A and SERV-B and each of these servers have their sperate e1, e2 servers. eg.. `SERV-A-e1, SERV-A-e2, SERV-B-e1, SERV-B-e2`. The code base is same.

```
resource - |
           |-SERV-A - |
                      |-application.properties
                      |-application-e1.properties
                      |-application-e2.properties


           |-SERV-B - |
                      |-application.properties
                      |-application-e1.properties
                      |-application-e2.properties
```

So I want that when I deploy my application on server SERV-A it should read application.properties and application-e1.properties files from `resource/SERV-A` and when I deploy it on server SERV-B then it should read from `resource/SERV-A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Anton Belev.

I was able to resolve this situation.
I recreated my `resource` structure.

```
resource - |
           |----------
                      |-application.properties
                      |-application-SerA-e1.properties
                      |-application-SerA-e2.properties
                      |-application-SerB-e1.properties
                      |-application-SerB-e2.propertie
```

So now when I want to deploy on SERVER-A. I can simply give a simple java command and have it running with correct sets of properties.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=SerA-e1 /path/to/jar/NameOFYourJar.jar &
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to achieve this using profiles based properties. [Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific). But you may need to play with the folder structure, you may need to bring `SERV-B` and `SERV-A` to the application properties name like `application-serv-a.properties` and `application-serv-a-e1.properties`. Obviously doesn't scale very much with many servers. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196451/environment-specific-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot-application/32197312)

I'd imagine you can leverage the active profiles like so:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=application-serv-a-e1.properties
```